# Unfamiliar notation found in a computer science book

Tags: boolean-expression

I'm reading through this computer science book and throughout the book I see a number of things written like so:

[image: example 1]

and then there's this:

[image: example 2]

and then this:[image: example 3]

What kind of notation is the "Boolean Expression" in example 1 written in? I've never seen anything like it before and I'm tempted to assume that whoever wrote and/or scanned this book in fell asleep at the keyboard, and assuming that it's even valid, what about the 3rd example? I'm pretty sure that's not C++ or VB.NET they're showing there.

Comment: I have no idea what bizarre notation is this. You should name the book and give precise references. And perhaps the book's bibliography could help.

Comment: That's *definitely* a typographical error.

Comment: Tend to agree with @BrianGordon. If this is an ebook, and especially a pirated copy, then chances of such typographic errors are higher, since a misaligned, hurriedly done OCR of a scan, can produce such gibbrish. That is compounded by text in/around graphic images.

Comment: Are you reading a physical book or an electronic version of it? You might be looking at typeset codes.

Comment: It's a pdf file of Dale - Computer Science Illuminated, 2002, and the screens are from various chapters around the book, I don't have it handy at the moment but the first one is from a section about logic gates, the second one from a section about numbering systems used in CS, and the third one is from an overview of high-level programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not valid notation. It looks like incorrectly rendered Latex.

If that's in a printed book, I suggest you go check the publisher's site for errata. If the entire book is like that, I'd demand a refund.

If it was a scanned document, then I would suggest that you go to your local university bookshop, and ask to see their second-hand books. Once a specific edition of a book is not being used for a course any more, it's usually sold back to the bookshop and resold for very little.

You can also find a fair amount of computer science materials online, for example at the MIT Open Course Ware site: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/ and MIT even makes available some video lectures: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6U-i4gXkLM

Something else MIT does is make some of their books available to be read online, like the [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html).

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that I understand is the Logic diagram and the Truth table. That's a representation of a NAND expression. So both inputs need to be 0 before the output is 1.